# Microsoft Bot SDK testing with local application

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I started working with Microsoft Bot Framework recently.
As a first step I created Echo example and tested with Emulator.
This was easy.

Now I want to test same Echo example with my website.
Have a chat window on website and send messages to get replies.

Can someone point me to the correct direction?
Most of the things I found are for Azure, WeChat etc. 
All I want to do is run my Bot locally and test echo functionality.
Thanks

Comment: have you got your web api hosted somewhere with SSL enabled?

Comment: WebChat is an official Bot Framework channel, as is the Emulator. To test with webchat locally, you will need to have a Bot Channels Registration in Azure, and use a DirectLine secret or token, and point the Messaging Endpoint to your local bot using tunneling software such as Ngrok.

Comment: Do I need to register my bot channel with Azure even if I am hosting myself (not using Azure). ?

Comment: The Emulator is the only channel the SDK can use without registering a bot with Azure Bot Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) library. It is a full featured solution that allows integrating you BotFramework bot into a web app, including passing data (bi-directional) between the app and the bot.

Setting up is SDK agnostic if you’re looking for simple integration. So it won’t matter whether you are using C#, Node, etc.

Hope of help!

Comment: Just for clarity, Eng Soon Cheah is correct that you can use the Direct Line channel for creating your own client application, if needed. However, the above library already uses Direct Line which is baked into the code. You need only configure to communicate with your bot, specifically.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into WebChat. Do I need to register my bot channel with Azure even if I am hosting myself (not using Azure). ?

Comment: Yes, as Direct Line is a feature of the Azure Bot Service. Once the bot registration is completed you can add the Direct Line channel under the Channels blade for your Azure bot. The Direct Line key is what WebChat uses to generate a token. The token is used for hosting the bot on your web page. Without it there would be no way for the embedded web chat to know what bot it should be running/displaying.

Comment: So even if I write my own client using Direct Line API  like @EngSoonCheah suggested, I still have to register it with Azure Bot service?

Comment: No, you don't have to. There is an unofficial NPM package you can download called "offline-directline" that creates a local direct line environment. You can find the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/offline-directline. However, creating an Azure account is free. And you can select the "F0" free tier for the bot registration which give you 10k messages/month to test against and access to all the channels. For testing locally, you would need to use ngrok to tunnel between your local bot and ABS. It's the easiest solution, really. But, I get you may have reasons to not register.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable your own client application to communicate with your bot by using the Direct Line channel.

Comment: So even if I write my own client using Direct Line API , I still have to register it with Azure Bot service?